# Port forward page not showing on ZTE H288A

Tags: router, port

I have Orange router ZTE H288A and it must show "Port forward" page in internet > security
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZVxv.png)
it should show it here but its not.
I will be very thankful if someone help me to show it.

Comment: is this your device, or one that is owned/managed by your ISP?

Comment: Hi, How to know ?

Comment: Only you will know. Did you buy this router yourself, or did it come from your ISP or as part of a service agreement/contract? It is not uncommon for devices managed by a company or organization to have limited settings compared with the full feature set of the device because the owner (not you) has different intentions for the device.

Comment: No, I bought it by myself.

Comment: Hello @music2myear ?, I bought it mate.

Comment: I am sorry if it appears otherwise, but I do not wait around for people to comment or reply. I don't know the answer to your question, I only know what additional info may be helpful. Given that you appear to own this device, it should have all or most of the settings documented for it. The fact it doesn't is something you may want to bring up with support for the product, probably after doing the basic things such as making sure you're running the most up-to-date firmware/software for the device.